# Authenticate with custom page Auth0

Tags: javascript, rest, auth0

I am new to auth0. I would like to host my own signup and login page. I managed to generate a signup page and successfully call `dbconnections/signup`, but I have no luck with the login. Currently I am trying `oauth/token` but I am getting "Authorization server not configured with default connection.”. Is there another API call that I can use for login (username + password)?

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings in Auth0 for your account. The dropdown at the top of your menu. 
At settings scroll down to Default Directory and put the name of your database there. Eg: Username-Password-Authentication

Answer (score 2):

Ive posted a detailed ansewr for how to move past this exact issue here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157069/3256123